# browser cache not getting updated even when the files are modified

Tags: html, browser-cache

Whenever I update my site with new files, I need to clear the cache every time to see the changes, which I don't want to do it...I have set expiration duration as 1 day,

Can anybody explain where is it going wrong and what's the solution?.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add random (or version-like) parameter to your scripts/css/images, like:

```
<script>document.write('<script src="script_path?' + Math.random() + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

wich makes browser to request like `script_path?0.611818` so script will nave get cached (actually it will, but always would  be requested a new copy).
Another way is adding version like parameter, e.g. current version of your web app is 5, so you do:

```
<script>document.write('<script src="script_path?' + your_version + '"\><\/script>');</script>
```

After each version you increase your_version parameter value by on or smth like that

p.s.

Examples are shown in js, but you will do it using your backend language

Answer (score 0):

To make the browser load a file `http://example.com/file.ext` from server every time instead of from the cache, change the client code to point to `http://example.com/file.ext?<random value>`. Every time you change the file, change the random value in the link.